# Multiple ifs in Smalltalk

Tags: refactoring, conditional-statements, smalltalk, pharo

I'm really new to smalltalk and still trying to figure out the basic stuff. Below is a simple program I wrote. 
It is supposed to print "a" if the number can be divided by 5, "b" if it can be divided by 3, and "ab" if it can be divided by 5 and 3. In any other case, the program just prints the number itself.
It certainly works like this, but I feel that the code isn't very pretty - I would like to avoid the third "if", but I'm really not sure how.
How would you refactor this?

```
1 to: 100 do: [ :i | 
  (i % 5 == 0)
  ifTrue: [ Transcript show: 'a' ].
  (i % 3 == 0)
  ifTrue: [ Transcript show: 'b' ].
  ((i % 3 == 0) or:  (i % 5 == 0))
  ifFalse: [ Transcript show: i ].
  Transcript cr.
].
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Smells like a [Fizz Buzz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz) problem! :-)

One approach in Smalltalk (Pharo) I've seen that I like is to use a dictionary with the Fizz and/or Buzz words as values and the booleans for whether it's divisible by 3 and 5 as keys. Once you have that, you simply look up the value for each index between 1 and 100. Oh, and don't bother dividing and checking whether the remainder is zero yourself - it's Smalltalk, so a number should know whether it's divisible by another number.

```
| fizzbuzz |
fizzbuzz := Dictionary
    with: #(true true)->'FizzBuzz'
    with: #(true false)->'Fizz'
    with: #(false true)->'Buzz'.
1 to: 100 do: [ :eachIndex |
    Transcript
        show: (fizzbuzz
            at: {eachIndex isDivisibleBy: 3. eachIndex isDivisibleBy: 5}
            ifAbsent: [ eachIndex ]);
        cr]
```

Have a look at some of the [other examples](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/FizzBuzz#Smalltalk) as well, sometimes the different approaches can be quite educational. I'll leave it to you to adapt the code to your 'a'/'b'/'ab' example.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would rewrite your version as:

```
1 to: 100 do: [:i |
    i % 5 = 0 ifTrue: [Transcript show: 'a'].
    i % 3 = 0 ifTrue: [Transcript show: 'b'].
    (i % 3 = 0 or: [i % 5 = 0]) ifFalse: [Transcript show: i].
    Transcript cr]
```

The changes are:

1. Use `=` instead of `==` (not a big deal)
2. Use `or: [i % 5 = 0]` with brackets

Another change you could introduce is

```
1 to: 100 do: [:i | | label |
    i % 5 = 0 ifTrue: [label := 'a'].
    i % 3 = 0 ifTrue: [label := 'b'].
    label isNil ifTrue: [label := i].
    Transcript show: label; cr]
```

Note that I'm not paying too much attention to the IFs but to the fact that `Transcript show:` appears three times in your code.

**EDIT**

Alas! My version above is not equivalent to yours because it will not print `'a'` if the number is divided by `5` and `3`!

**EDIT 2**

Here is how to reproduce the behavior of the original code:

```
1 to: 100 do: [:i | | label |
    label := ''.
    i % 5 = 0 ifTrue: [label := 'a'].
    i % 3 = 0 ifTrue: [label := label , 'b'].
    label isEmpty ifTrue: [label := i].
    Transcript show: label; cr]
```